# Kivy Widgets doesn't shows up

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, kivy

Im getting a strange error. I can only see **black window** without text label. I've also tried many other widgets and gets the same bug!

It came up after I fixed -
**Kivy does not detect OpenGL 2.0** by setting environmental variable
KIVY_GL_BACKEND = angle_sdl2

I even tried uninstalling python3.7.3 and installed python3.7.7, Then installed Kivy according to Kivy official docs still the same issue:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#installation

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
import kivy

# the minimum OpenGL version supported by Kivy:
kivy.require('1.9.1')

# defining app class:
class HelloKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello, Kivy")

# running the window:
HelloKivy().run()
```

console log:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\AVD\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-04-20_66.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.17
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.9
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.22
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Program Files\Python 3.7.3\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Program Files\Python 3.7.3\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <angle_sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b"OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.b'')">
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Google Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics Direct3D11 vs_4_1 ps_4_1)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b"OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 (ANGLE 2.1.0.b'')">
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Ouput Window:
[Image of output window which shows only a black background without showing the text label](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iTkdxrktJkWlSrwgWjJt-eUNOt1nVq-P)

---

I have also posted the thread on many other forums:

on Python Forum: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Kivy-Kivy-text-label-won-t-shows-up

on Sololearn: https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/2271231/kivy-text-label-won-t-shows-up

on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/geeyyd/kivy_widgets_wont_shows_up/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Edit: Thanks to all for the help!

Comment: try to add a diff. color to the text of the label,

Comment: @ChitkaranSingh tried it, no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after restless troubleshooting I came to the solution.

- The issue was due to my old crappy integrated intel-made graphics card, arising conflicts with my os, and kivy!
- It was very hard to troubleshoot as Kivy and OpenGL claims to work correctly while the issue is still there!
- I should either purchase a new graphics card or try installing unofficial graphics driver if available to make kivy work well in my pc.

(Special thanks to Snu at kivy discord)

Answer (score 0):

instead of OpenGL, use sdl2

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_TEXT'] = 'sdl2'
os.environ['KIVY_IMAGE'] = 'sdl2'
```